# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null?

Tags: laravel, migration, laravel-seeding

I got this error when try to seed database.

Laravel 7.

#### BlogPost Model

```
class BlogPost extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'slug',
        'user_id',
        'category_id',
        'excerpt',
        'content_raw',
        'content_html',
        'is_published',
        'published_at',
        'updated_at',
        'created_at',
    ];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(BlogCategory::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

#### User model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

#### User migration

```
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

#### BlogPost migration

```
        Schema::create('blog_posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('category_id');
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->text('excerpt')->nullable();
            $table->text('content_raw');
            $table->text('content_html');
            $table->boolean('is_published')->default(false)->index();
            $table->timestamp('published_at')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('blog_categories');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

#### User seeder

```
class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $users = [
            [
                'name' => 'Author',
                'email' => 'seriiburduja@mail.ru',
                'password' => bcrypt('some1234')
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'Admin',
                'email' => 'seriiburduja@gmail.com',
                'password' => bcrypt('some1234')
            ]
        ];

        DB::table('users')->insert($users);
    }
}
```

#### BlogPost Factory

```
$factory->define(BlogPost::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    $title = $faker->sentence(rand(3, 8), true);
    $text = $faker->realText(rand(1000, 4000));
    $isPublished = rand(1, 5) > 1;
    $createdAt = $faker->dateTimeBetween('-6 months', '-1 day');

    return [
        'category_id' => rand(1, 10),
        'user_id' => 1,
        'title' => $title,
        'slug' => Str::slug($title),
        'excerpt' => $faker->text(rand(100, 400)),
        'content_raw' => $text,
        'content_html' => $text,
        'is_published' => $isPublished,
        'published_at' => $isPublished ? $faker->dateTimeBetween('-6 months', '-1day') : null,
        'created_at' => $createdAt,
        'updated_at' => $createdAt
    ];
});
```

#### DatabaseSeeder

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call(UserTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(BlogCategorySeeder::class);
        factory(BlogPost::class, 1)->create();
    }
}
```

When i run `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` i got this error.

Tables users and blog_categories seeds successfully, but error appear for blog_categories.

I don't understand why.

Field **user_id** exists in $fillable in BlogPost Model.

If i change migration for blog_posts and add a nullable for user_id, than seed work, but user_id is null. But i don't need that.

Thansk in advance.

Comment: add a `dd([/*return result*/ ])` in your blogpost factory to make sure it's being hit correctly and generates reasonable data.

Comment: @apokryfos
Done. 
```
    $result = [
        'category_id' => rand(1, 10),
        'user_id' => 1,
        'title' => $title,
        'slug' => Str::slug($title),
    ];
    dd($result);

```

And user_id
```
  "category_id" => 4
  "user_id" => 1
  "title" => "Voluptatem vel blanditiis dignissimos eligendi culpa ratione molestias accusamus."
  "slug" => "voluptatem-vel-blanditiis-dignissimos-eligendi-culpa-ratione-molestias-accusamus"

```

Answer (score 0):

In Blog Post Model

Change user relationship to

```
public function owner()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

In User Model
Add this relationship

```
public function blogposts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(BlogPost::class);
}
```

In Database seeder don't use UserSeeder Directly create user in DatabaseSeeder

```
public function run()
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => "Your name",
        'email' => "youremail@gmail.com",
        'password' => Hash::make('YourPassword')
    ]);

    $this->call(BlogCategorySeeder::class);
    
    $user->blogposts()->saveMany(BlogPost::factory(1));
}
```

In BlogPost Factory remove user_id

```
return [
    'category_id' => rand(1, 10),
    'title' => $title,
    'slug' => Str::slug($title),
    'excerpt' => $faker->text(rand(100, 400)),
    'content_raw' => $text,
    'content_html' => $text,
    'is_published' => $isPublished,
    'published_at' => $isPublished ? $faker->dateTimeBetween('-6 months', '-1day') : null,
    'created_at' => $createdAt,
    'updated_at' => $createdAt
];
```

**fillable** is not required when you are using Seeder to insert data.

If you want to insert each and every column in database then you can use **guarded** property which is opposite of **fillable**.

Comment: Thans for answer.
I was a little sick and couldn't answer yesterday.

I got an error when try to seed data. 

```
 Call to undefined method App\BlogPost::factory()

```

Comment: Make this change ***"use App\Models\BlogPost";*** and then try again